# Understanding JavaScript object properties (functions) referencing other properties in same object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects, readability

So I have stumbled upon a React Hooks based component that uses objects to categorize various functions for readability.

For eg.

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const utilities = {
    utility1: () => {
      // ...some functionality
    },
    utility2: () => {
      // ...some functionality
    },
  };
  
  const renderers = {
    renderer1: () => {
      // ...some rendering logic
    },
    renderer2: () => {
      // ...some rendering logic
      return (
        <span>{renderers.renderer1()}</span>
      );
    },
  };

  return (
    // ...rendering logic
  );
};
```

What I want to understand is why is `renderer2` working correctly even when it calls `renderer1`?

What I understand is that the object will be declared when the code is executed and the declaration is not complete till all properties are defined (this is just my noob understanding, I may be entirely wrong).

I would be really interested in knowing why this little bit of code works, especially why does it work correctly?

Also, on a side note, compared to Class-based components, I feel Hooks-based components are not very readable, and this approach tries to mitigate the problem. *So I was wondering if this is the best way to make a Hooks-based component readable, or if there are other better approaches for the same?*

Comment: It's all a matter of [scope](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What I understand is that the object will be declared when the code is executed and the declaration is not complete till all properties are defined*

This is not so. A variable declaration happens ahead of time - at compile time, before any code actually has had a chance to run. The assignement to a variable happens at runtime though. This includes evaluating the value being assigned.

So in the case you're talking about, when the object being assigned to `renderers` is being evaluated, the `renderers` variable is actually already declared.

Also, you have to consider the fact that `renderers.renderer1()` is not actually being called as part of the evaluation of this object - but only later on when `renderers.renderer2()` is actually be called, at which point both the object evaluation and the assignment will have completed, and thus `renderers.renderer1()` will be what you expect it to be.

Comment: Oh right! The fact that it is called later on makes SO much sense! Like, that line clicked it all together in my head. Thanks a lot :)